# getInvitationId() of BaseGameActivity returns always null on real device

Tags: android, google-play-games

I am using google play game services invites. When the user launches the app I check the invitation id to see if the app is launched with an invitation. On emulator it works fine but on Samsung s4 mini the invitation id is always null. I am extending the BaseGameActivity and calling getInvitationId(). Is this a bug or a misconfiguration on my part?

Basically I am trying to do the same thing what ButonClicker sample app does.

Answer (score 0):

I have an app that runs on the Samsung S4 built on the same BaseGameActivity. I have the same implementation of onSignInSucceeded()

```
@Override
public void onSignInSucceeded() {
    // if we received an invite via notification, accept it; otherwise, go
    // to main screen
    String invitationId = getInvitationId();
    if (invitationId != null) {
        // TODO accept the invitation...
        return;
    }
    ...
}
```

And this has been working for my app.
If you modeled it off the ButtonClicker app, it seems it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It must be a mistake on my part. I will get back to acknowledge when I figure it out.

Comment: I discovered the same problem. It works with no problem on a Samsung Galaxy S3 with Android 4.3 but crashes with the nullpointer exception with a Nexus 5 with 4.4